# AWS Amplify 'currentUserCredentials()' returns unexpected authenticated value, bug?

Tags: amazon-web-services, vue.js, aws-amplify-cli, aws-amplify

When calling Auth.currentUserCredentials() after Auth.signIn() I get valid valid credentials, but for an unauthenticated user, why?

**Code:**

```
   async signIn({ dispatch, state }, { email, password }) {

  try {
    const user = await Auth.signIn(email, password);
    console.log("User state after login")
    const userCredentialsAfterLogin = await Auth.currentUserCredentials();
    console.log(userCredentialsAfterLogin)

  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error")
    console.log(error)
    return
  }
  await dispatch('fetchUser')
},
```

**Expected behaviour:**

After signing in with a valid user, Auth.currentUserCredentials() should return an authenticated set of Credentials.

**Actual behaviour:**

Auth.currentUserCredentials() returns an unauthenticated user with the authenticated property set to **false** and a 400 error, "**ResourceNotFoundException: IdentityPool 'eu-west-1:62dab5ed-5a84-4064-a7a2-87d1d0df511b**'

**System:**

- authenticationFlowType: "USER_SRP_AUTH"
- Versions: "aws-amplify": "^3.3.14", "aws-amplify-vue": "^2.1.4", amplify version 4.42.0

**config**

```
{
  "authSelections": "userPoolOnly",
  "resourceName": "testapp89e81d50",
  "serviceType": "imported",
  "region": "eu-west-1"
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I understand where you're coming from, and honestly I can't really show you clear documentation that exactly states why this won't work. AWS documentation on Cognito and Amplify is difficult to piece together, both because the Amplify framework still uses an old library under the hood ('amazon-cognito-identity-js') and Cognito is the name for both a connect-login-with-IAM and signup/signin-as-a-service offering. Cognito is super powerful and rock solid in terms of security if done right, but the setup is a bit of a pain.

There's a bit of documentation, e.g. the API docs of Amplify Auth [here](https://aws-amplify.github.io/amplify-js/api/classes/authclass.html#currentcredentials). You can see there that currentCredentials / currentUserCredentials gives you some [object](https://aws-amplify.github.io/amplify-js/api/interfaces/icredentials.html) which contains among other things an 'identitiId'. Credentials, in the Amplify Auth framework, refer to AWS IAM credentials that refer to an Cognito Identity.

You seem to be using Amplify to login to a Cognito User Pool, using email/password. A Cognito User Pool can be connected to a Cognito Identify pool, to 'exchange' a Cognito JWT token for some credentials that can be used to use AWS resources (IAM credentials). This is not needed to have a normal sign in / sign up flow working though.

So, the question is: what do you want?

1. Do you want to know about the currently logged in Cognito User Pool user, e.g. his email, JWT token and other fields that are stored in the JWT token? Use 'currentUserInfo' or 'currentUserSession'
2. Do you actually want to have some IAM credentials to invoke AWS resources? Make sure to create and connect your Cognito User Pool with a Cognito Identity Pool and configure your Identity Pool id in your frontend settings. If you've done that, you should be able to use 'currentCredentials'.

Comment: Hi Bram, thank you for the detailed reply. I might have to read it again to fully digest. Maybe I have misunderstood some of the fundamentals. In regards to what I want to do. I have 2 things. The first is to determine if a user is logged in, the second is to obtain the JWT for interacting with a server or API. i.e. maybe Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()?

Comment: I tested the following "const user = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()" and I still get a blank session. I imported my UserPool, maybe setup is incorrect.

Comment: I just updated the OP with my AWS Config. Looking at the value "userPoolOnly" and trying to understand your point 2.

Comment: What is the result of 'Auth.signIn'?

Comment: Auth.signIn give me back the a user object and is successful, userID, dcb1ebe3-32d1-46a8-93ed-c0c1ed31dc1d including attributes like email and sub. Session is null.

Comment: Seems strange behaviour, maybe something in the config isn't working. Maybe check the local storage if you can find the JWT token, it should be stored and visible there.

Comment: I just used 'Auth.currentSession()' and decoded the JWT which gives me the correct user but Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser() gives me an unauthenticated user

Comment: I get this and a 400 error then calling "Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()" : ```{__type: "ResourceNotFoundException",…}
message: "IdentityPool 'eu-west-1:62dab5ed-5a84-4064-a7a2-87d1d0df511b' not found."```
__type: "ResourceNotFoundException"

Comment: I think I have found the same issue here https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/2702 without a fix

Comment: I do not have any federated user pool, just a cognito user pool, is this the issue?

Comment: It looks like it is configured like there's an identity pool, but in fact there isn't. Double check your config to see if you've set some property that is supposed to be the identity pool. If you do not have an identity pool, this property should be empty/not set.